# How to set background repeat linear gradient css in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I want to add this css in `canvas`

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( 129deg, #000, #000 10px, #f69d00 10px, #f69d00 20px );
```

I found that `createLinearGradient()` method and `createRadialGradient()` method, but I am not able to add `degree(angle)` init.

Comment: Post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

`createLinearGradient` and `createRadialGradient` are methods of CanvasRenderingContext2D object for drawing, so they do not affect CSS propaties of canvas element as `background`.

You can use style propety of, canvas element to set background, like this.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const deg = 129;
canvas.style.backgroundImage = `repeating-linear-gradient( ${deg}deg, #000, #000 10px, #f69d00 10px, #f69d00 20px )`;
```

NOTE: Background image is NOT canvas graphic, so when you invoke `toDataURL` or `toBlob` method the output image has NO background.